# How to copy and paste a clicked shape from one slide to another

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am new to VBA in PowerPoint and I am trying to develop an interactive program for my class where a text box grouped with a bubble shape floats across the screen and they have to click it if they notice it contains a certain grapheme. I want the clicked text boxes to copy to another slide so that I can assess if the children have been successful or just clicked anything they saw.

I've pieced together this code from other sites:

```
Sub copyobject()
With ActivePresentation
Set myshape1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes(group5)

myshape1.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = myshape1.Copy

.Slides(3).myshape1.Paste
End With

End Sub
```

It doesn't appear to be working though. Can anybody help me out?

The error message I receive is 'compile error: method or data member not found' with .myshape1 highlighted.

If anybody could give me a completed code for this or correct what I have created I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks

Comment: if `group5` is your group name, write `"group5"` as a string inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the error still remains though.

Comment: I have managed to fix it by using this code:Sub copyobject()
With ActivePresentation
Set myshape1 = ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes("group 5")

myshape1.Copy

.Slides(3).Shapes.Paste
End With

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of the object is "group5", I assume it's a group. But you can't apply an Action Setting to a group, only to a single object. This works for a single shape:

```
Sub copyobject()
  With ActivePresentation
    Set myshape1 = .Slides(2).Shapes("Rectangle 1")
    myshape1.ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Action = myshape1.Copy
    .Slides(3).Shapes.Paste
  End With
End Sub
```

BTW, an excellent VBA book for what you're doing is David Markovitz's [Powerful PowerPoint for Educators](http://evergreen.loyola.edu/marco/www/PowerfulPowerPoint/ExamplesFromRealPeople.html). His support site for the book also has lots of free code and samples.